# Android - How to iterate through a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, radio-button, loops

I have a ListActivity with each row in the list containing 2 TextViews and 4 RadioButtons.

The 2 TextViews are populated from a SimpleCursorAdapter pulling data from a table in my database and the 4 RadioButtons are just placed into the xml code (with their ids being assigned to 4 RadioButton variables in the Java code.

Basically what I want to do is check the state of each radio button in each row to update my database accordingly.

How would I access each row of RadioButtons to check to see if they are checked or not?

I apologize if this is vague, I will try to add more detail if needed.

Many thanks.

```
private void processAttendance(){
    int index = 0;
    this.allStudentsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchEnrolledStudents(mRowId);

    lvList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    this.allStudentsCursor.moveToFirst(); 

    while (allStudentsCursor.isAfterLast() == false) { 


         this.radGroup = (RadioGroup) lvList.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.attendanceGroup);
         this.mAttended = (RadioButton)lvList.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.presentRadio);    
         this.mLate = (RadioButton)lvList.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.lateRadio);    
         this.mExcused = (RadioButton)lvList.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.excusedRadio);    
         this.mMissed = (RadioButton)lvList.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.absentRadio);
         this.mStudentId = allStudentsCursor.getLong(allStudentsCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")); 
         this.mResult = "";





    if(mAttended.isChecked()){  
        this.mResult ="attended";
        radGroup.clearCheck();
    }
    else if(mExcused.isChecked()){  
        this.mResult ="excused";        
    }

    else if(mMissed.isChecked()){   
        this.mResult ="missed";     
    }
    else {  
        this.mResult ="late";       
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
    String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    this.mDbHelper.addAttendance(date, this.mResult, this.mStudentId, mRowId);
     allStudentsCursor.moveToNext(); 
     index++;
    }




    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is fundamentally flawed -- ListView doesn't inflate a different layout view hierarchy for each row, it keeps only enough needed to fill the screen.  As one scrolls off the edge, it is re-used to show the data for the next one scrolling in.

The data inside of each row in the list *must* come from the data in the cursor.  If it isn't, it will be lost when it scrolls off the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to loop over the `Cursor`.

```
myCursor.moveToFirst();
/* Loop over all items */
while (myCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
    //get radio button
    RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
    /*
     Edit or Check myRadioButton
     */
    myCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

This is a quick example showing just one `RadioButton` but you get the picture.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the quick response. I am now wondering how I would set my Long rowId variable from the current position in the iteration through the Cursor? Any ideas? As I'm sure you can tell I'm rather new to Android Development so Sorry if my questions are stupid and tedious :)

Comment: you would use `rowId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));`

Comment: this long value seems to remain at 0 everytime it iterates through and I check it in the debugger, what would be the reason for this do you think? If it was null then the program would crash right as I didn't think long values could be null?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about that. I changed my instance variable to Long instead of long and now it works. Thank you so much for all your help - you've saved me hours of frustration :)

Comment: Hello again, I am having trouble with the radio buttons. The problem is when iterating through the cursor. The first row in the list is fine but for any subsequent rows the value is being taken from whatever radio button was clicked in the first row. So if the 1st of 4 radio buttons is checked in the first row it will go through adding to the database for the rest of the rows saying the 1st radio button was checked even if it wasn't. How do i access which radio button was checked in the 3rd row for instance?

Comment: That's the method above containing the code. I'm probably missing something obvious or may need a new approach to this.

Comment: and where are you calling `processAttendance()` from?

Comment: I have a confirm button at the bottom of the Activity. processAttendance() is called when this is pressed.

Comment: You may need to set an `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` for each checkbox and check the values there.  I can't think of a way to get your current implementation working without it :-\

Comment: Do they need to be added to the listAdapter?

Comment: I would have them declared in the main Activity, I can't see any other way of getting the specific row each checkbox lives in.  Again, this is just how I would attempt doing it, it may not work.

Comment: I finally got it working! I declared a ListView instance variable and then set that to the ListView in the layout. From there I can call on the children at that index from the list view to access the radio buttons. I've updated the code sample above to show the change. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The views are recycled in a list view so if you have say 20 items in list you may only actually have 5 instances of RadioButton. Once the view is off the Screen it gets recycled.

What you need to do, is whenever a RadioButton is clicked, change the data behind the list that determines whether the radio needs to be checked.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. What would be the best way to change the data behind the list to stop this happening? I guess I may need to rethink the design of the whole activity? I'm an Android newbie so I'm still finding my way (as I'm sure you can tell from my questions!)